# Jenkins : What is this changelog.mustache?

Tags: jenkins

I get below exception every time I run a build on jenkins which ultimately results in build failure.
What is this changelog.mustache file and where can I get it? Thanks.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find on classpath (changelog.mustache) or filesystem (/changelog.mustache).
    at se.bjurr.gitchangelog.api.GitChangelogApi.getTemplateContent(GitChangelogApi.java:417)
    at se.bjurr.gitchangelog.api.GitChangelogApi.render(GitChangelogApi.java:365)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitchangelog.perform.RemoteCallable.call(RemoteCallable.java:130)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitchangelog.perform.RemoteCallable.call(RemoteCallable.java:29)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1077)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitchangelog.perform.GitChangelogPerformer.performerPerform(GitChangelogPerformer.java:28)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitchangelog.GitChangelogRecorder.perform(GitChangelogRecorder.java:44)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1047)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: changelog.mustache (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at com.google.common.io.Files$1.getInput(Files.java:105)
    at com.google.common.io.Files$1.getInput(Files.java:102)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:249)
    at com.google.common.io.Files.toByteArray(Files.java:197)
    at com.google.common.io.Files.toString(Files.java:223)
    at se.bjurr.gitchangelog.api.GitChangelogApi.getTemplateContent(GitChangelogApi.java:414)
    ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mustache is a template. [Here](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) more info.

Is the template [configured](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Changelog+Plugin)?

Comment: I am not sure, how can i check.

Answer (score 1):

Probably same issue as reported here:
https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-lib/issues/32

I'm guessing you use it with a pipeline script and that you ar missing the template.